# Enable Fortran program with recursive subroutine to run with gfortran on Windows

Tags: fortran, quicksort, gfortran

The quicksort program at https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort#Fortran runs as is, sorting 50 numbers, but when `nl` is set to 100 so that 500 numbers are to be sorted, the program hangs, when I compile with gfortran 13.0.0 20221218 on Windows 10. I have tried the `-frecursive` and `-fmax-stack-var-size` options without success.

How can I make the program run on Windows for larger array sizes?

Comment: Note that -frecursive and -fmax-stack-var-size are mutually exclusive. Or in a way, you can think of -frecursive as -fmax-stack-var-size=INFINITE. Windows generally has quite a small max stack size limit (per se unrelated to Fortran), you might want to look into increasing it.

Comment: What does means precisely "The program hangs" ? Please be more specific.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut indeed, by looking at the others versions on this RC page I can spot other problems (for instance the Matlab version that returns an array with more elements than the input array.

Answer (score 0):

The code is buggy. It is missing an increment/decrement once a swap has been performed. It results in an infinite loop in the case where the left and right values are both equal to the pivot value.

```
       ! Partition loop
       DO
          IF (left >= right) EXIT
          DO
             IF (A(right)%VALUE <= pivot) EXIT
             right = right - 1
          END DO
          DO
             IF (A(left)%VALUE >= pivot) EXIT
             left = left + 1
          END DO
          IF (left < right) THEN
             temp = A(left)
             A(left) = A(right)
             A(right) = temp
             left = left+1    !!! MISSING !!!
             right = right-1  !!! MISSING !!!
          END IF
       END DO
```